# How to set the line space between two chunks in itextsharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I am creating a PDF using iTextSharp. This is a reporting tool. Everything is working fine, only the space between two chunks is slighly greater that what I want. I tried to find some help on StackOverflow and got to know `SetLeading(fixed, multiplied);` but it is not coming with `chunk` in case.

The reason I need it in chunk is that I have multiple chunks which I am adding into paragraph proceeding to which adding all into Document at a single shot.

```
public static void createPDF(Paragraph para)
    {
        string imagepath = "12.pdf";
        Document doc = new Document();
        try
        {

            Paragraph p = para;
            Rectangle[] COLUMNS = {
            new Rectangle(36, 36, 290, 806),
            new Rectangle(305, 36, 559, 806)
          };

           //This is what i have tried
           // p.SetLeading(0.4f,0.8f);
            p.SpacingBefore = 0.0f;
            p.SpacingAfter = 0.1f;

            PdfReader inputPdf = new PdfReader(@"");
            PdfWriter writer2 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(imagepath, FileMode.Create));



            doc.Open();
            PdfContentByte canvas = writer2.DirectContent;
            for (int ij = 1; ij <= 3; ij++)
            {
                doc.SetPageSize(inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation(ij));
                doc.NewPage();

                PdfImportedPage page = writer2.GetImportedPage(inputPdf, ij);
                int rotation = inputPdf.GetPageRotation(ij);

                if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
                {
                    canvas.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, inputPdf.GetPageSizeWithRotation(ij).Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    canvas.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                }
            }

            doc.NewPage();
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
            int side_of_the_page = 0;
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);
            int paragraphs = 0;
            int i = 0;

            while (paragraphs < p.Count-1)
            {
                string TEXT = p[i].ToString();

                ct.AddElement(p[i]);
                while (ColumnText.HasMoreText(ct.Go()))
                {
                    if (side_of_the_page == 0)
                    {
                        side_of_the_page = 1;
                        canvas.MoveTo(297.5f, 36);
                        canvas.LineTo(297.5f, 806);
                        canvas.Stroke();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        side_of_the_page = 0;
                        doc.NewPage();
                    }
                    ct.SetSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);

                }
                i++;
                paragraphs++;

            }

            doc.Close();
        }
        catch {


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [chapter 2 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf). The `Chunk` object is called the *atomic* building block among iText's high-level objects. By design, **you cannot define a leading on the level of a** `Chunk`.

I quote from page 23:

> A `Chunk` isn't aware of the space that is needed between two lines.

The leading is defined at the level of a `Phrase` (and, of course, its superclasses, such as `Paragraph`). If you want to change the spacing between `Chunk` objects, you need to wrap `Chunk`s in `Phrase`s or `Paragraph`s (as you already indicate) and define the leading for those phrases or paragraphs.

Note that the documentation also states:

> In normal circumstances you'll use `Chunk` objects to compose other text objects, such as `Phrase`s and `Paragraph`s. Typically, you won't add `Chunk` objects directly to a `Document`.

Which special circumstance do you have that requires making an exception to this rule?

**Extra remarks**

1. You are importing an existing PDF in a way that throws away all existing interactivity. This is suboptimal.
2. You first compose a paragraph `p`, you set the leading for `p`, then **you decompose p throwing away the leading you've defined** and then you complain that there's no leading.

This is what you are doing wrong:

```
while (paragraphs < p.Count-1)
{
    ct.AddElement(p[i]);
    ...
}
```

The object `p` knows its leading; the separate components of this object (`p[0]`, `p[1]`,...), don't know anything about the leading.

Hence you should do something like this:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
int side_of_the_page = 0;
ct.SetSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);
ct.AddElement(p);
while (ColumnText.HasMoreText(ct.Go()))
{
    if (side_of_the_page == 0)
    {
        side_of_the_page = 1;
        canvas.MoveTo(297.5f, 36);
        canvas.LineTo(297.5f, 806);
        canvas.Stroke();
    }
    else
    {
        side_of_the_page = 0;
        doc.NewPage();
    }
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[side_of_the_page]);
}
```

As you have defined the leading at the level of the `p` object, you must add the `p` object as an element to the `ColumnText`.

**Regarding the wrong way you're copying the original document:** The [`AddLongTable`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/stamper/AddLongTable) example shows how to do it correctly. You get a `PdfReader` object for the existing document. You create a `PdfStamper` to create a new document. You get the number of pages in the existing document, and then you use `insertPage()` as many time as needed to add extra content.

Comment: Ok Sir .I corrected my mistake.Now i am adding chunk into Paragraph and trying to set SetLeading in the paragraph like this `p.SetLeading(0f,0.8f)` but it is not doing any changes why?

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using? In old versions, the method only worked in the context of `ColumnText`. You need a recent version. You aren't by any chance using an obsolete fork of iText, are you?

Comment: I don't like the way you import the existing PDF. I don't feel like answering the question because you're not using `PdfWriter` instead of `PdfStamper`.

Comment: Also: you first compose `p`, you set the leading for `p`, then you decompose `p` **throwing away the leading you've defined** and then you complain that there's no leading. This is the equivalent to somebody who gets a cake, eats it, and then complains that he didn't get a cake...

Comment: I've updated the answer, but please be more accurate when asking questions in the future.